# Can you spot enemies above or below you using the heartbeat sensor in Warzone?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

Recently I watched youtubers stream and they said that the heartbeat sensor can show you if your enemies are below or above you. So is it really true? And if it is, how do we spot it in the sensor?

Answer (score 4):

The heartbeat sensor doesn't have any kind or vertical indication. However, you can still somewhat use it to at least *deduce* where someone may be within say a building. If you are on the ground floor and use the heartbeat sensor in conjunction with clearing the ground floor, if you are still getting a senor reading, then you know they are either above or below you. Knowing building layouts can help you even more. For example, most houses in Warzone don't have basements, so if you know the ground floor is clear, any sensor readings would indicate that someone is upstairs.

Another way to deduce the vertical position of a reading is if you are getting a heartbeat that shows someone very close to you, but obviously no one is in sight. That would indicate that they must be above or below you.